# Contact Layout Editor not working CiviCRM 5.19.2

Tags: contact-layout-editor

I have installed the contact layout editor extension on Drupal 7 and could not see editor when selecting contact summary layouts.  I upgraded CiviCRM to version 5.19.2, enabled Shoreditch still nothing. All extensions are shown up to date.  All I see when selecting the editor is this error messsage

Notice: Undefined index: target_contact_name in getContactActivitySelector() (line 2608 of /home/webdevelopmentsc/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Activity/BAO/Activity.php). =>

Any help or assistance would be appreciated.

Regards

Graham

Comment: can you check the civicrm log file for more details.
before that clear you cache, /civicrm/menu/rebuild url

Comment: Cache cleared and repeated the selection.  I enabled error reporting.  Great stream under logfile location.  This is the 8 element array under the error message, Notice: Undefined index: target_contact_name in getContactActivitySelector() (line 2608 of /home/webdevelopmentsc/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Activity/BAO/Activity.php). =>

Comment: This is array listing 7: CRM_Activity_BAO_Activity::getContactActivitySelector() (Array, 2 elements)
 6: CRM_Activity_Page_AJAX::getContactActivity() (Array, 2 elements)
 5: CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem() (Array, 2 elements)
 4: CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke() (Array, 2 elements)
 3: CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke() (Array, 2 elements)
 2: civicrm_invoke() (Array, 2 elements)
 1: menu_execute_active_handler() (Array, 2 elements)
 0: main() (Array, 2 elements)

Comment: php 'Notice' won't stop loading the page, can you check civicrm log file.?

Comment: Thanks.  I set the Enable Drupal Watchdog Logging to Yes, so all CiviCRM errors should appear in Drupal watchdog.  Am i missing something?

Comment: I switched on the developer console on the browser.  This is some of the output.  I spotted a 403 regarding api4.  I hope that helps.jquery.min.js:formatted:721 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ul.menu a[href=/]
    
VM1832:1 POST https://www.web-developments.co.uk/civicrm/ajax/api4 403

Comment: Im also getting this error in Drupal 7.69, CiviCRM 5.21.0 Contact Layout Editor v 1.4.3 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () (api4, line 0)